# Amsul DateTimePicker - How to unselect active date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using amsul DateTime picker (https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/) where if you see in the preview the today's date is highlighted in green. Now if you move the calendar to the next month or previous month. Every month's today's date is also highlighted.

How do I unhighlight any other dates then today's date?

```js
$('.datepicker').pickadate()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/classic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/classic.date.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/classic.time.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/picker.js"></script>
<script src="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/legacy.js"></script>
<script src="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/picker.date.js"></script>
<script src="https://hateable-tests.000webhostapp.com/picker.time.js"></script>
  <input type="text" class="datepicker">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive this is the answer:
https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/issues/805

> **ilnee** commented on 2 Oct 2016
>
> I ran into this issue as well. As a workaround, I remove the
> picker__day--highlighted class from every div with that class that
> doesn't have today's timestamp as data-pick value:

```
var now = new Date();
var timestamp = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()) / 1;

$('.datepicker').pickadate({
    onRender: function() {
        $('div.picker__day--highlighted').each(function(index, value) {
            if ($(this).data('pick') !== timestamp) {
                $(this).removeClass('picker__day--highlighted');
            }
        });
    }
});
```